# How to change SharePoint List column size and color

Tags: 2010, list, column

Hi i created an out of the box custom list.  I was wondering if in the standard view if it is possible to increase the font size and perhaps color of the column headers?  Is there an easy way to do this?  This would be in SharePoint 2010.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many alternatives to apply different styles for tables. This reference gives a list of the most used http://davidandrewsmith.us/2011/06/30/sharepoint-2010-css-list-of-useful-styles/

To apply those, use a Content Editor web part to inject the styles, or if you use any list view as web parts inserted in the page, you could customize totally the XSLT via the XSL link or you could customize the master page and include the CSS as part of it.

Comment: FWIW - if you do use a Content Editor while editing a view page, do NOT put it as the first web part on the page.  Microsoft added an API call in SP2010 that reads the first web part on a view page and expects it to specify the underlying list.  If another web part is there, it will break functionality in strange places.

Comment: Didn't actually know that, thank for the tip! It does happen that I've always added all at the end.